# Prevent empty lines collapsing in IE on contenteditable=false

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, rte

I have a div with `contenteditable=true` set in order to allow inline editing (for RTE purposes).

Im aware different browsers handle the enter keypress differently, FF inserts `<br>` and IE inserts `<p>`

The issue I am experiencing is when entering text across various lines.

e.g for the text:

```
line 1
line 2

line 3


line 4
```

In FF, when entering the above then switching `contenteditable=false`, the line formatting remains as expected.

However, when editing in IE with multiple lines of text, then setting `contenteditable=false`, any blank lines are collapsed. e.g:

```
line 1
line 2   
line 3    
line 4
```

If I then reset `contenteditable=true`, these collapsed lines are restored.

I am guessing it has something to do with the use of `<p>` by IE, any ideas how I can prevent the lines from being collapsed when `contenteditable=false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to walk around this IE-behavior by catching ENTER, and adding `BR` instead of `<P>&nbsp;</P>`.

```
pad.addEventListener('keydown',keyDown,false);

function keyDown(e){
    if(e.keyCode!=13) return;
    pad.innerHTML+='<br />\b';
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

<div id="pad" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

The trick is to add "\b" (backspace) to the end of the line, otherwise IE won't make newline before user hits another key. However, these backspaces are causing troubles when using `innerHTML` later. To remove backspaces, you just replace them with `""` with RegExp:

```
padsInnerHTML=pad.innerHTML.replace(/LITERAL_BACKSPACE_CHARACTER/g,'');
```

In the regexp you'll need a literal backspace character, `/\b/` won't work. To actually see the backspace character, you can run your code in Opera with this `keyDown()`, write some letters and hit ENTER in `pad` and copy-paste the character to your code.

Notice, that this code should run in IE only, other browsers will mess up with newlines.

---

Why is this working, I don't know. It seems, that IE adds some none-printing character after `<BR />`, which has to be removed to create an instant newline after pressing ENTER.

Comment: This does work, but prevents the native behaviour of IE adding <p> tags around newline content, which then stops block commands using execcommand from working on a line by line basis (i.e. centering text will center all text, not the current line). It seems when adding a new line with contenteditable=true, IE inserts <p>&nbsp;</p>, but when switching to contenteditable=false it trims these empty <p> tags, collapsing the section. I wrote a routine to manually add them back into empty <p> tags to maintain the newline